# Returning an Observable from an Observable in Angular HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors, ngrx-store-4.0

Am using *@ngrx/store* to get a token from store and placing it in HTTP headers, I tried using flatmap mergeMap but they all keep duplicating the http requests and when I use take(1) it goes on loop request and hangs, this is what I have:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
   token$: Observable<string>;

   constructor(private readonly store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
      this.token$ = store.select(fromAuth.getToken);
   }

   intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return this.token$
               .map(token => {
                  if (token) {
                     request = request.clone({setHeaders: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}});
                  }
               })
              .mergeMap(() => next.handle(request));
   }
}
```

Comment: you probably just need to use switchMap and actually pass your modified request through the stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return this.token$
           .map(token => {
              if (token) {
                 request = request.clone({setHeaders: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}});
              }
              return request;
           })
          .switchMap((req) => next.handle(req));
```

Switch map takes one observable and switches it into another.  You also need to actually pass a value through when using map in an observable sequence. I personally would even make the request a part of the initial observable stream.

Comment: it still doubles the requests made from client for each HTTP request

Comment: you probably also need take(1): `this.token$.take(1).map(...).switchMap(...)`

Comment: I'm gona go out on a limb and say your observable is doubling requests because you've accidentally subscribed twice somewhere. have you confirmed it only runs once if you don't intercept?

Comment: I added the take one and passed the value to switchmap and now it works thanks